# Serving favicon.ico with Django. Why does settings.MEDIA_URL with django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to only work on dev environment?

Tags: django, favicon, django-staticfiles

I found this solution for serving favicon.ico with django.

```
(r'^favicon\.ico$',
  'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to',
  {'url': settings.MEDIA_URL+'images/favicon.ico'}),
```

I do not understand why it only works for the development server.
Going to /favicon.ico works on dev, doesn't with `debug=False`.
It should redirect to /media/images/favicon.ico (served by apache), which does work if you access it directly.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is MEDIA_URL set to when it doesn't work?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I'd recommend against serving the favicon with django unless you absolutely have to. Instead, putting a setting in your web server config that adds an alias pointing to the favicon.

For example, in apache:

```
Alias /favicon.ico /path/to/media_url/images/favicon.ico
```

Comment: Agreed. Just went to my shared hosting, got it to work putting an exception for lighttpd (I thought it was apache serving the stuff)

Answer (score 29):

This is not direct answer to you question, but you can use this for favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: That works for the website, but sometimes browsers & tools try to access /favicon.ico directly.

Answer (score 16):

redirect_to has been [deprecated in Django 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11429714/908294). You can use the class based RedirectView

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^favicon\.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url=settings.MEDIA_URL + 'images/favicon.ico'))
)
```

Comment: hmm for me it works in firefox, but not in Chrome. What can be the reason? I cleared cache of course..

Comment: @andi Some software looks for `favicon.ico` in the root of the domain, some follow the `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="...">` HTML, and some software looks elsewhere. This site is useful for checking that your favicon is good for most software: http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker