# "No module named simple" error in Django

Tags: django

```
ImportError at /
No module named simple

Django Version: 1.5.dev20120710212642
```

I installed latest django version. I am using

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to
```

in my urls.py. What is wrong? Is it deprecated?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Use [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/#class-based-generic-views) instead of `redirect_to` as these function-based generic views have been deprecated.

Here is simple example of class-based views usage

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^about/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html")),
)
```

**Update**

If someone wants to redirect to a URL, Use [RedirectView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView).

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^one/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/another/')),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this example. We just upgraded to 1.5 and instantly got errors with both redirect_to and direct_to_template. Upvoted.

Comment: How can I do it using `path`?

Answer (score 53):

this should work

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'some-url', RedirectView.as_view(url='/another-url/'))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this example. We just upgraded to 1.5 and instantly got errors with both redirect_to and direct_to_template. Upvoted.

Comment: Thank you! works like a charm! Actually, THIS is the correct answer to the question. The accepted answer is not a replacement for redirect_to.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the old function-based generic views were deprecated in 1.4. Use the class-based views instead.

Comment: What can I use instead of redirect_to?

Comment: @Burak, how about RedirectView.as_view(url='/another-url/') as indicated above?

Answer (score 5):

And for the record (no relevant example currently in documentation), to use [RedirectView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview) with parameters:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.views.generic import RedirectView


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^myurl/(?P<my_id>\d+)$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/another_url/%(my_id)s/')),
)
```

Please note that although the regex looks for a number (`\d+`), the parameter is passed as a string (`%(my_id)s`).

What is still unclear is how to use `RedirectView` with `template_name` in `urls.py`.