# return redirect in django 1.5 throwing import exception

Tags: django

I have simple code that basically looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
def my_view(request):
    ... does stuff
    return redirect('/some_other_url/')
```

The exception being thrown is "Could not import django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to. Parent module django.views.generic.simple does not exist." When I comment out the "return redirect" code (and replace with return HttpResponse("")) I no longer get the error.

stack trace: *NO Longer availalbe because it was posted outside SO* http://dpaste.com/1007500/

I just upgraded from django 1.3.1 to django 1.5. Checking the documentation for 1.5 it looks like I should still be able to use "redirect()". I could not find any answers to this from several google searches so hopefully its not some blind oversight on my part.

Comment: return redirect('/app_name/some_other_url/')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    ... does stuff
    return redirect('/your_app/some_other_url/')
```

Comment: princess, I just looked at my urls.py and found     url(r'^favicon\.ico$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to',    {'url':  '/static/favicon.ico'}),

When I comment that out, it no longer throws the "Could not import django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to" exception. Thanks for the idea - I will just accept your answer.

Comment: hai princess can you help me out the same problem for reverse migrating from 1.3 to 1.5 reverse('name')
showing the same error...

Comment: The provided code isn't any different to what's in the question.

Answer (score 11):

Looks like problem not in `django.shortcuts.redirect`, but in view, that process url you were redirected to. According to your traceback, view, that process url 127.0.0.1:8000/post_station/ use somewhere django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to. In django 1.5 you problably shouldn't do it. Use `django.views.generic.RedirectView` insead.

You can find answers here ["No module named simple" error in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428427/no-module-named-simple-error-in-django)

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed an issue with using simple.redirect_to in my urls.py file.