# Django / From redirect_to to RedirectView

Tags: python, django

Since you know, we can't use from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to in Django 1.5. However we were using this kind of functions in our views.py:

`return redirect_to(request, '/auth/login/')`

I want to migrate from 1.4 to 1.5 but I couldn't figure out how to use RedirectView in views.py with request and url argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`redirect` instead](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

Now you can simply change the `redirect_to` to

```
return redirect('/auth/login')
```

Comment: would it return the `request` as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/#class-based-generic-views) or [RedirectView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView)

RedirectView helps you to redirect your url which works as like redirect_to. Both are applied in urls.py. But I couldn't find any solution to redirect from views.py.

Source: ["No module named simple” error in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428427/no-module-named-simple-error-in-django)