# No module named 'django_simple.todo'

Tags: python, django

I am working through a (mycodesmells) django tutorial  and towards the bottom under "ADDING TO THE PROJECT" it says to update the url.py file with the code that it gives.

Once I update that file it crashes the server and gives me the error.
"No module named 'django_simple.todo'

I looked in SO posts and template view and redirect were mentioned in the following post.
1. Does this mean its deprecated?
2. How do i fix or adjust the code for Django 1.1 and Python 3

[Templateview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428427/no-module-named-simple-error-in-django)

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django_simple.todo import views as todo_views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', todo_views.index),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular library, but the name is "todo" so maybe you are expected to do it?  Or perhaps it was supposed to be created at some step in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have an `__init__.py` file in the "todo" folder. That lets Python know it's a module.

Also make sure you have django_simple.todo in your Django apps list in your `settings.py`.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you please upvote & mark as accepted answer? I'm trying to get my new badge, lol.

Comment: I don't have a todo folder, it didnt say to create one.

Comment: You have to, since "todo" is an app. It requires all your view, model, & form Python files. Try reviewing that tutorial one more time

Comment: Why do tutorials routinely leave out information in them, its pathological.

If your going to do a tutorial give the user instructions each step otherwise they get lost and give up, then your tutorial is not reccomended.